# Firefox CSS3 object-fit: cover strange behaviour during transition

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions

I have `img` inside the `div` with exact `width` and `height`. I would like to place image there like `background-size: cover` to fill entire `div` so HTML is:

```
<div class="cover">
    <img class=active src="http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/02/26/17/56/clock-650753_640.jpg" alt="time">
</div>
```

And CSS is:

```
.cover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
}

.cover img {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;

    -webkit-transition:visibility 0s linear 4.0s,opacity 2.0s linear 2.0;
    transition:visibility 0s linear 4.0s,opacity 2.0s linear 2.0s;
}

.cover img.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is live example http://jsfiddle.net/sytwrd9L/1/ - 2 seconds after load the image disappears. In the Firefox 36 it resizes the `img` during transition but in other browsers it works well. Any idea how to fix not to resize `img` during transition in FF?

Comment: Since this is a Level 4 spec experimental property I doubt if there will be many workarounds as yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but today I found a workaround for this issue. I've tested it in Firefox 44.0 so far.

The Workaround:

```
<!-- Apply the transition to this element -->
<div class="transition">
    <!-- Apply a 3D translate to this element -->
    <div class="translate3d">
        <!-- Apply object-fit to this img elemnt -->
        <img src="path/to/img.jpg" class="object-fit" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, your solution is working I have just tested it: http://jsfiddle.net/sytwrd9L/7/

Comment: It looks like a bug in Firefox, in my case the same happens just by assigning a different value for, eg., the 'top' property, even with no transition: `image.style.top = '10px'`. The image will "squish" for a brief moment. Applying the transform to a parent element is the only fix apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't applying `translate3d(0,0,0)` to an element *inside* a transitioned element prevent the GPU from accelerating the transition itself?

It's the transitioning element you want to accelerate, right? But you're applying the translate3d hack that invokes GPU acceleration to an element without transitions.