# Firefox object-fit cover property ignored during transition animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

On Firefox, when jquery is animating a transition between 2 images (by doing a fade in/out effect), the image's object-fit property seems to get ignored, yielding to a skewed image!

Here's a link that demonstrates the issue, the top slideshow part that shuffles through images:
http://www.tooride.com/

The jquery code that I execute to cycle between images:

```
var idx = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var elementFadeOut = images[idx];
  $(elementFadeOut).animate({opacity:0}, fadeTime, function() {
    elementFadeOut.style.display = "none";
  });

  // fetch the next index
  idx++;
  if(idx >= numImages) {
    idx = 0;
  }

  var elementFadeIn = images[idx];
  elementFadeIn.style.display = "block";
  $(elementFadeIn).animate({opacity:1}, fadeTime);
}, visibleTime);
```

CSS used for the img:

```
#tourfilters-slideshow img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Everything is fine for Safari & Chrome. But Firefox skews the image only while transitioning.

I even tried the bootstrap carousel, and modified their `img` to be `width:100%` with a defined `height:200px` and `object-fit:cover` (by inspecting in the browser and making the modifications), the same issue occurred in Firefox:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox CSS3 object-fit: cover strange behaviour during transition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28939689/firefox-css3-object-fit-cover-strange-behaviour-during-transition)